# Accessing C++ native DLL (with namespaces) through JAVA

Tags: java, c++, dll, namespaces, java-native-interface

I have a c++ DLL where the functions are nested within namespaces.

I need to access these functions in java.. i'm not much of a java expert but i do know a little of its basics.

I found basic java codes to access methods in C++ native DLL using JNI but im not sure how to access the functions nested within namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to get the mangled names of the C++ functions.  You can use `nm` to do that on Unix or `dumpbin /exports` on Windows.  The mangled name will have the namespace and function name, so it should be easy to find (unless there are several overloads with the same name that you need to distinguish).  Are you sure the functions are normal C++ functions and not class methods?

Comment: The structure is something like:
namespaces>classes>static methods.

And i also do have the headerfile of the dll.. //thinking would that even help ...

Comment: @Mafahir: Static methods will work just fine -- it's non-static ones that will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favour : use [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) for C++ interop, it should be able to deal with most namespace issues :-)

(disclaimer : I'm BridJ's author)

Answer (score 0):

"Jeremiah Willcock" answer is right, in any case, you can always access a D.L.L. functions, inside classes or namespaces using "mangled names", its the weird, dirty way of doing things, but, its works, even if there are other ways.

You could do some tests, accesign those functions, and later, make your own wrapper.